# Display messages from Firebase asynchronously in NativeScript ListView

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, rxjs, nativescript

I am trying to display simple messages asynchronously in a ListView. The messages are fetched from Firebase via [the de-facto standard NativeScript Plugin](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-plugin-firebase). I do not think there is anything wrong with my plugin interaction as I am able to initialize, login and even recieve the messages. I just can not get them to display in a ListView.

I managed to map the event-callback from the Firebase message pushing to an observable by creating an EventEmitter. Im not sure if this is the right way to go but it has shown the best results as I can see the messages being pushed through my observable.

**Here's what I am doing:**

```
import { Component, OnInit, EventEmitter } from "@angular/core";
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable";
import * as firebase from "nativescript-plugin-firebase";
import { Message } from "./shared/message.model";
@Component({
    selector: "my-app",
    templateUrl: "app.component.html"
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    public messages: Observable<Array<Message>>;

    ngOnInit() {
        this.init()
            .then(() => this.login())
            .then(() => this.getMessages());
    }

   // ... implementations for init() and login(), also post()-method

    getMessages = () => {
        let msgs = [];
        // initialize with asynchronous behaviour
        let emitter = new EventEmitter(true);
        this.messages = emitter;
        // shows messages getting added to array
        this.messages.subscribe((a) => console.log(JSON.stringify(a)));

        firebase.addChildEventListener((result) => {
            msgs.push(new Message(result.value.text, result.value.timestamp));
            emitter.next(msgs);
        }, "/messages");
    }
}
```

**And this is the view:**

```
<GridLayout rows="auto, *">
    <GridLayout row="0" columns="*, auto">
        <TextField #textInput hint="Type message..." col="0"></TextField>
        <Button text="Post" (tap)="post(textInput)" col="1"></Button>
    </GridLayout>

    <ListView row="1" [items]="messages | async">
        <template let-item="msg">
            <StackLayout>
                <Label text="a message"></Label> <!-- displays after button click -->
                <Label [text]="msg.text"></Label> <!-- results in exception when there even are items -->
            </StackLayout>
        </template>
    </ListView>
</GridLayout>
```

I can see that the subscription is working so far as every array variant gets logged incrementally, but my view is not displaying them. I tried different modes for the ChangeDetectionStragety, which did not seem to make a difference.

I found out that when I have a button in my view which calls a component-function I can see the elements after clicking it. Yet, if there are bindings to the let-variable in my view like `[text]="msg.text"` the application crashes with the following error:

```
An uncaught Exception occurred on "main" thread.
com.tns.NativeScriptException: 
Calling js method getView failed
[object Object]
File: "/data/data/org.nativescript.firebasetest/files/app/tns_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js, line: 9464, column: 20
StackTrace: 
Frame: function:'ListViewComponent.detectChangesOnChild', file:'/data/data/org.nativescript.firebasetest/files/app/tns_modules/nativescript-angular/directives/list-view-comp.js', line: 134, column: 29
Frame: function:'ListViewComponent.onItemLoading', file:'/data/data/org.nativescript.firebasetest/files/app/tns_modules/nativescript-angular/directives/list-view-comp.js', line: 114, column: 14
Frame: function:'Observable.notify', file:'/data/data/org.nativescript.firebasetest/files/app/tns_modules/data/observable/observable.js', line: 146, column: 32
Frame: function:'ListViewAdapter.getView', file:'/data/data/org.nativescript.firebasetest/files/app/tns_modules/ui/list-view/list-view.js', line: 199, column: 28  
// ... native stacktrace
```

What am I doing wrong? Why does it have to be so hard to implement an async list in NativeScript when it is arguably easy in Angular? The documentation is a bit weak here..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your firebase-connector is running outside the angular-zone, maybe wrapping your next-call in an `ngZone.run` helps:

```
import { Component, OnInit, EventEmitter, NgZone } from "@angular/core";
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable";
import * as firebase from "nativescript-plugin-firebase";
import { Message } from "./shared/message.model";
@Component({
    selector: "my-app",
    templateUrl: "app.component.html"
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    public messages: Observable<Array<Message>>;

    constructor(private ngZone: NgZone) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.init()
            .then(() => this.login())
            .then(() => this.getMessages());
    }

   // ... implementations for init() and login(), also post()-method

    getMessages = () => {
        let msgs = [];
        // initialize with asynchronous behaviour
        let emitter = new EventEmitter(true);
        this.messages = emitter;
        // shows messages getting added to array
        this.messages.subscribe((a) => console.log(JSON.stringify(a)));

        firebase.addChildEventListener((result) => {
            this.ngZone.run(() => {
                msgs.push(new Message(result.value.text, result.value.timestamp));
                emitter.next(msgs);
            });
        }, "/messages");
    }
}
```

Also this might help: https://github.com/NathanWalker/angular-seed-advanced/wiki/How-to-integrate-Firebase-across-all-platforms-(web-nativescript-desktop)

Comment: Thanks, this helped me very much. My view now enumerates the messages, yet I still can not bind to properties of a message in my template without getting the former "getView failed"-exception. Any ideas on that?

Comment: Fixed it like Nick Iliev suggested

Answer (score 3):

Apart from the ngZone related issue there is also a syntax mistake in the item template. Change this `<template let-item="msg">` to

```
<template let-msg="item">
```

See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41184518/4936697) for details.

Comment: You are correct, I made it work by naming it "item" in some step but I didn't quite grasp what I did to fix it. Thank you very much for your help, sadly I can only accept one answer as correct.